# Migration to Elasticsearch 8 Python

Tags: python, elasticsearch

After updating Python package of elasticsearch from 7.6.0 to 8.1.2, I started to receive an error after creating the client:

```
es = Elasticsearch("https://es.mysite.net:9200", basic_auth=("username", "password"))
es.info()
```

The error message is the follow:

> The client noticed that the server is not Elasticsearch and we do not support this unknown product

My version of Python is 3.8.3.
Install everything required from https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/blob/main/dev-requirements.txt

What can the solution consist of?

Comment: Hey from the url ... aren't you talking to `Kibana` instead of `Elasticsearch` server ? Shouldn't you have `https://elasticsearch.mysite.net` ?

Comment: Sorry, the server is Elasticsearch, not just Kibana. I am correcting the description of the case so as not to confuse anyone anymore.

Comment: What version do you have on your Elasticsearch instance  ?

Answer (score 2):

You can try downloading the version to identify the source of the error or rule out that possibility.

```
pip install 'elasticsearch<7.14.0'
```